# Generating code at build time depending on configuration, in VueJS

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-cli

I have a VueJS/vue-cli application with a few views. I would like to enable/disable some code depending on a build-time configuration.

This is not strictly related to development/production, but say for example that my application has 3 features, and I want to have 2 different builds depending on who I am shipping the product.

For example, say I have the views Foo, Bar and Baz: I want to have the Foo view in my generated static files only when building for Deploy1, Bar only when building for Deploy2 and I always want to see Baz for every deploy.

Naturally, the code relative to Bar should not be included in the Deploy1, therefore I am not talking about a run-time check.

This is conceptually similar to what `#ifdef` macros can do in C.
How can I achieve a similar result in VueJS and vue-cli? (Or NodeJS in general?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe I'll use gpp (https://github.com/logological/gpp), but a vue/node specific solution is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm using multipe entry points for the build script : 
In my package.json :

```
 "develop:foo": "vue-cli-service build --mode develop --dest dist/foo --target app ---modern src/foo.js",
 "develop:bar": "vue-cli-service build --mode develop --dest dist/bar --target app --modern src/bar.js",
```

now in foo.js and bar.js it's pretty strightforward : it's the equivalent of your main.js hence you include whichever plugins, components in your app

In my case I was using the same code for two version of the app but of them includes more features than the other so for example in one of my version I'm not including websockets, I'm not including some third party api ... etc.

You can seperate pretty much anything.

I hope that answered your question !

Comment: Thanks! This is interesting, but if you provide different main.js files, how do you ensure that code from one build is not included in the other? I mean, even if it is unused, it still present, isn't it?

Comment: Well I'm generating two apps  in `dist/foo` and `dist/bar` : seperate directories.

Comment: I'm serving both of the apps from a S3 bucket (Object storage for AWS) on a CDN (different base urls )

Comment: Ok, that was clear, but I still don't get how do you ensure that code related to `foo` is not present in `bar`. Do you have a MWE?

Comment: To make it more clear: say that both `foo.js` and `bar.js` use a file `baz.js` that has functions that are relevant to both, but exclusively. Say `baz.js` contains `func_foo` which is used by `foo` and `func_bar` that is used by `bar`. When you build `foo`, how do you make sure that `func_bar` is not included in the code?